# Java - Change var type into a subclass without losing field values

Tags: type-conversion

I have a question on Java:

Right now, I have a main class, called **Property**, and some classes that extend it, for example **PropertyFoo** . So, the *Property* class has a field called **name**.
So, I need to do something like this:

```java
Property boo = new Property();
boo.name = 23;
if (someCondition) {
    boo = new PropertyFoo();
}
```

But I need the boo, that now is a *PropertyFoo*, to have the old *name* var, so if now I call boo.name it returns 23. Is there any way to do this?
Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom constructor and pass it the value of the field you want to preserve and assign it to the same field in the new object within the custom constructor.

Something like this within PropertyFoo:

```
public PropertyFoo(int name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Call:

```
PropertyFoo foo = new PropertyFoo(boo.name);
```

Comment: No problem! You can create any number of custom constructors and pass them anything.